# Manga where the main character is reborn in a game as a child villainess who hangs out with the two male leads in a greenhouse

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

The male leads wear collars for some reason and are mages, and one of them is a yandere who freezes the heroine of the game in ice in a bad ending. I remember that the male leads pretend to be kidnapped at one stage in the story.

This is a black & white manga.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Also, when you say "green house," do you mean a regular house that is coloured green, or a [mostly-glass structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse) in which plants are stored?

Comment: glass they grow flowers / it was not coloured so i dont remember

Comment: Since you described this as a "reborn as a villainess" manga, is the main character the heroine that was frozen in ice, or was that a separate character?

Comment: sorry i could of been more clear she was reborn into a game and when she explains the plot she mentions the ml freezes the heroine in a bad ending

Comment: Who is it that pretends to be kidnapped?

Comment: male leads but that a little bit into the story

Comment: And the main character is reborn as a child villainess?

Comment: yes at least up to the point i remember she was still a child

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate the additional info you provided in the comments. If I misunderstood or incorrectly phrased anything, please edit the question yourself to fix it.

Comment: I managed to find it while doom scrolling its called The Reincarnated Princess Strikes Down Flags Today as Well (Thank you for helping me and while writing this i see you edited the question too be more clear. i really mean thanks you made my day. )( im going too leave this open for a bit so you can read this then ill close it thanks again)

Comment: If you like, you can post the answer yourself and potentially earn some reputation. If you do post the answer, please don't forget to mark it as accepted in roughly 48 hours (the earliest that the site will allow you to do that).

Answer (score 5):

***[The Reincarnated Princess Strikes Down Flags Today as Well](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/psrm325/tensei-oujo-wa-kyou-mo-hata-wo-tatakioru)***.

> Who cares about being cute?! Rosemarie is a young girl who got reincarnated in the world of a dating sim. That game was famous for being a crappy game full of hopeless men! She has a bad feeling about it, but she has no time to waste getting upset about it! She's going to change the peculiar dateable character for the better and meet the man she really loves at all costs!